# How important is maths depending on what your coding?

Tags: learning, algorithms, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does mathematics have to do with programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136987/what-does-mathematics-have-to-do-with-programming)
>   [How often do you have to solve pure mathematical or algorithmical problems?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/how-often-do-you-have-to-solve-pure-mathematical-or-algorithmical-problems)

I heard that math can be very important in programming. I am a confident python programmer, and have started C++.

So far I have not encountered anything where I need to use any real math. 
I have had to use logic and a bit of problem solving, but that's about it.

I also wanted to know: does a particular part of coding (software engineering or game development) use maths more?

Comment: Maths is a huge subject. What do you mean by "real math"?

Comment: L4xord, I think these are two different questions, and also that they both have already been answered: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/136987/what-does-mathematics-have-to-do-with-programming and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/how-often-do-you-have-to-solve-pure-mathematical-or-algorithmical-problems

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I mean practical maths, like algebra and algorithms. That kind of maths.

Comment: Thanks for the links, Jalayn. The question can be closed now.

Comment: It is quite true that Mathematics is invlovled in Game Development. **Random numbers**, **2D and 3D Graphics**, and **Mechanics (or Applied Maths/ Calculus)** does constitute a major part in Game Development. It also depends on what level of Game Development you are doing. If you are developing games with the help of a Game framework, you wouldn't need much Maths. But if you are creating a framework for developing games yourself, then you have to know some Mathematics there!

Comment: Programming is a Computer Science activiy and hence Mathematics plays a vital role there. But if you consider to be a mere IT professional and like to learn programming based on a certain technology then you can definitely learn it and become an expert in that area without much Mathematics. If you are a CS undergrad or Maths fanatic and like to  learn programming in general from the very core foundation, wants to go in detail and arugments then do read the book "**The Art of Computer Programming**" authored  by ***Donald Knuth***.

Comment: The real answer to "How important is maths depending on what you're coding?": "How important is maths depends on what you're coding!". I almost never need higher maths in my day job, yet depended on it when I did Computer Graphics and other things in my spare time. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends completely on what kind of systems you program. But your experience is common: most programming is done on workflow support systems of one kind or another, which rarely require any math.

But there are fields where this is different: scientific computing, obviously. 3D graphics (but not so much if you use an engine someone else developed). Algorithmic trading.

Comment: Thanks Michael, my dad is a scientist who uses programming for things like data computing. So he was the one who always (and still does) tells me how important maths is. Through I'm more into game dev and software design and development.